# Access denied on a log in via firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem. I want to log me into via a firestore database. The thing is I receive "access denied". When I click on "network" in the inspector in the browser, I receive a 403 error message. Passwort and Email is correct, in another android app I can log me in with this data. I authorisated localhost as a domain. Where is my mistake? Thank you in advance!

**error**

```
  <Error>
      <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>16AC88BE19DA980D</RequestId>
    </Error>
```

**login.js**

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.


    //document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "block";
    //document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "none";

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if(user != null){

      var email_id = user.email;
      //document.getElementById("user_para").innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + email_id;

    }

  } else {
    // No user is signed in.

    //document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "none";
    //document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "block";

  }
});

function login(){

console.log("login");
  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);

    // ...
  });

}

function logout(){
  firebase.auth().signOut();
  console.log("logout");
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js"></script>




<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    ...
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
<script src="login.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please make sure you tag your questions with the correct programming language.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem it is the correct language. JavaScript + Firestore

Comment: It is now.  It wasn't when you posted it.  Doug Stevenson fixed it for you.

Comment: Ohhh, I'm sorry. I didn't saw that.